# Remote access to a Java enabled mobile phone from PC

Tags: remote-control, mobile-phone, j2me

Is there any program that enable remote access to a Java phone from the PC?
I have to configure several devices (Bluetooth access / device name, permissions, certificates, "desktop" shortcuts, applications and so), and if I could access the devices remotely then I can automate and simplify the process, specially in the case of non-local customers that actually send me the mobile phones to configure them in my office.

Comment: Specific details about which hardware your using is required.  What mobile operating are you using exactly?

Comment: @Ramhound: currently, I'm using a Nokia C2-01 phone (S40, MIDP 2.1) on the mobile side and Windows 7 on the desktop side